# Load XML into memory and change attribute wherever found using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have bellow xml template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Items>
    <TextItem Name="" Text="_Brand" Font="" />
    <TextItem Name="" Text="_Model" Font="" />
    <BarcodeItem Name="" Symbology="Code128" Code="_Brand" />
    <BarcodeItem Name="" Symbology="Code128" Code="_Model" />
  </Items>
</Root>
```

I need to change some attributes from the template file in memory to avoid changing the physical file. The attributes to change will be defined by the `_Brand` and `_Model` variables.

The idea is to change the `_Brand` *wherever found* by let's say: AA and `_Model` *wherever found* by BB

I only know that I can load the xml file using either `XDocument` or `XmlTextReader` but I don't know how to do the rest.

This should be the xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Items>
    <TextItem Name="" Text="AA" Font="" />
    <TextItem Name="" Text="BB" Font="" />
    <BarcodeItem Name="" Symbology="Code128" Code="AA" />
    <BarcodeItem Name="" Symbology="Code128" Code="BB" />
  </Items>
</Root>
```

Comment: do a simple google search then `C# Load XML into memory and change attribute`

Comment: @MethodMan did you read my question, is a bit different to the ones I've found on google.

Comment: What do you want the xml to look like after the change? It's not clear to me from your question. Also, what are you going to do with it after the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the fact that it's xml. Just load it as a string and use the [string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Hmm. That seem to beat iterating the `XDocument.XElement.Attributes()`. Probably lots faster too.